# Priority/Decision Based Choice of Row

Tags: r

I have a data.frame that has a number of duplicate rows, akin to something like this:

```
con <- textConnection(Lines <- "
First, Last, Address, Address 2, Email, Custom1, Custom2, Custom3
A, B, C, D, F@G.com,1,2,3
A, B, C, D, F@G.com,1,2,2
A, B, C, D, F@G.com,1,2,1
")
x <- read.csv(con)
close(con)
```

Now, when I de-duplicate, in the following manner:

```
x <- x[!duplicated(x[,c("email")]),]
```

Could you recommend a method for prioritizing those rows that contain Custom3=1? Or is there a better mechanism for de-duplication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try sorting before finding duplicates:

x <- x[order(x[,c("Custom3")]),]
x <- x[!duplicated(x[,c("email")]),]

Comment: Good suggestion, I didn't even think about sort order being a factor, but it definitely makes sense.

Comment: My suggestion won't work if you want to say prioritize Custom3==2, but in that case perhaps code verbosity is better than a one liner. So my solution isn't so universal, but rather specific to your query.